# Textbox to filter all values that matches in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using below VBA code to filter the data by typing starting words in textBox and it works great.

The issue i have been facing is when i type any numeric value and alpha middle, end or any other value that is available in filter range it does not work.

for example i have data in Col"C" that is

```
King
Tomb
River
Ocean
8899
1011
4568
```

I will type "Ki" or "To" or "Ri" starting words/value code will work.

when i type midlle, last or numeric value it will not work such as "mb", "ver", "ean" or any numeric value "4568", "11".

There could be any solution which can work this way.

You help will be appreciated.

```
   Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim textb_deger As String, bul As Range
    Dim start As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    textb_deger = TextBox2.Value
start = Sheets("AutoFilter").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set bul = Range("C4:C" & start).Find(What:=textb_deger)
Application.Goto Reference:=Range(bul.Address), Scroll:=False
Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=textb_deger & "*"
If textb_deger = "" Then
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
End If
Set bul = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your data is a mixture of numeric values and text values.  In order to implement filtering that **Contains** the sub-string `11` rather than **BeginsWith** `11`, all the data must be Text.  *(whether the data looks like a number or not)*.

Once that has been accomplished, you can use something like:

```
Criteria1:="=*" & textb_deger & "*"
```

For example:

[image]

**All** the data in this example is *Text*.  Running this code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As Worksheet, textb_deger As String
    
    Set s = ActiveSheet
    
    textb_deger = "11"
    
    s.AutoFilterMode = False
    s.Range("A:A").AutoFilter
    s.Range("A:A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & textb_deger & "*"
End Sub
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Gary's Student thank you so much for the help. Can you please share that why i cannot use this same code twice for combobox1 and combobox2. Whe, i do this just 1st is work not second combobox works

Comment: @Learning  I am sorry.....I can't debug that behavior without actually examining the workbook.

Comment: Ok , than you can please share that where i need to upload the sheet so that you can examine it.